# What framework/app executes the lockscreen on android 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lock-screens

Im looking to modifying and perhaps changing the way the lockscreen works. I have heard about keyguard.apk but I cant seem to find that in system/app or anywhere in the device. So I wonder which file executes the lockscreen code and contains the resourcea.

Comment: It's usually the System-UI itself. Either `SystemUI.apk` or `/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk` (ART devices).

Comment: yeah I decompiled it but couldnt seem to find any resources or code relating the lockscreen.

Comment: did you look for keyguard? additionally you could check the AOSP: frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a awhile since I went hunting around those files but I believe its in \system\framework\framework-res.apk